# Ensuring o(log(n)) search times in SQL on a partitioned table without knowing the index

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm working on a project where we have a partition created from a table everyday. I'm trying to ensure near real-time speeds for cancelling a request, for that, I need to get an item from that table.

What I have are two unique keys, and a date in my hands. I unfortunately don't have the database set up yet for this test, this is being implemented later on, so I'm wondering how does that search work internally.

Considering I would have 30 partitions at the end of the month, how do I know my query is starting on the "freshest" date? I could use a SQL function to grab the date and check the day. The other possible solution is just to throw the unique keys in there, and expect that the search is fast enough.

So, with that, my questions are:

1. How to ensure that my search is starting on the newest partition?
2. Does the usage of one or more unique keys guarantee some BinarySearch speed for a search?
3. If #2 doesn't guarantee it, which other options would you think for it?

I don't need any code or implementation, I just need this theoretical question answer so I know how to ensure what I'm doing since I have the absence of a testing environment (or time to do it on my own).

Comment: Assuming you have an actual SQL query, say, `SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE condition`, then just put `EXPLAIN` in front of it: `EXPLAIN SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE condition`.

Comment: Ooooh, I totally forgot about EXPLAIN! Thanks! I will try that, I can probably create some tiny database here for this purpose.

Comment: Basic SQL indexes are binary trees (B-Tree), guaranteeing binary search complexity.

Comment: In a tiny database it may decide it's quicker to just scan the whole table instead of bothering with an index.

Comment: In my case it won't be a tiny database for production, I'm just trying to get to it without a test environment (I don't have one ready to go here).

Comment: You're looking for an explain result that says that an index is being used. That'll do it.

Comment: depends on your db too, all kind of stuff can happen to plans over time, oracle e.g. allows you to freeze one of your chosing.

Comment: you could also de-normalize if needed and put the identifying columns in a index organized table, so you get a lookup at maximum speed.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I don't receive an index for this. I will receive a request to fetch this UNIQUE value, and I gotta find it as fast as possible in 30 days of data in near real-time. If I had an index my life would be a lot easier.

Comment: @NikolaiDmitriev would you expand on that as a possible answer for this question? As a reminder, I don't know the index of it. I just receive a request with the UNIQUE key and gotta find it in the midst of 30 days of data.

Comment: @NikolaiDmitriev well, that's what I'm trying to avoid, doing a full table scan. I need a log(n) result.

Comment: You should be able to name some application requirements for the db design, don't you? ask for an index.

Comment: Sure, that I'm doing. The thing is, the application won't know the index of the element inserted in the table because we cannot save millions of indexes since we don't know which one will be requested. That's an arbitrary decision.

Comment: luke, I can't post an answer here. your requirements actually contradict horizontal partitioning, since you search can target any partition, and all will need to be kept in memory, or permanently swapped in and out of memory, except you put each of them on a separate server. I'm positive oracle has options for that, also for distributed queries. It points a bit to apache spark and Haddoop if your data really gets huge.

Comment: Btw there was a terminological issue here, Luke thoght of indexes like for java arrays (`items[i]`) rather than rdbms-indexes, b*-trees and stuff. after clarification an rdbms index organized table looked like a viable thing.

Comment: @OrangeDog: actually a "B-Tree" is a "balanced tree", not a binary tree.

Comment: I think it's more of that the indexes will exist, but I won't know them in the application because the places of the items being searched will be random. Either way, I got the main thing: it will be o(log(n)), I just have to make sure how to enforce it to start on the newest data, and not the old one